After I deploy an Azure Web function, the corresponding function is not generated in the interface
I want to make a chat room. I follow the step with MS tutorial.
My folder is like figure1.

But the function doesn't be create. When I go to azure portal, I saw the Function app is created successfully, but their is no any function can be trig (fig2).

I use function start locally and it works fine, but I put it in azure and it doesn't work.
here is my message.js code (I apologize for not being able to reveal the contents of the function getAIResponse, but I don't think this program affects the deploy function.)
const { WebPubSubServiceClient } = require('@azure/web-pubsub');
const { app: azureApp } = require('@azure/functions');
const { OpenAIClient, AzureKeyCredential } = require("@azure/openai");

const connectionString = process.env["AzureWebPubSubConnectionString"];
const hubName = 'simplechat';
const serviceClient = new WebPubSubServiceClient(connectionString, hubName);

// Azure Function (PubSub WebSocket)
azureApp.http('message', {
    methods: ['POST', 'OPTIONS'],
    authLevel: 'anonymous',
    handler: async (request, context) => {
        if (request.method === 'OPTIONS') {
            return {
                status: 204,
                headers: {
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST, OPTIONS',
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type, Authorization',
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'X-Requested-With, content-type',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            };
        }

        try {
            const body = await request.json();
            const message = body.messages;
            if (!message) {
                return {
                    status: 400,
                    headers: {
                        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({ error: "Message is required", data: request })
                };
            }




            const aiResponse = await getAIResponse(body);
            await serviceClient.sendToAll(aiResponse, { contentType: "text/plain" });

            return {
                status: 200,
                headers: {
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(aiResponse)
            };
        } catch (error) {
            return {
                status: 500,
                headers: {
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({ error: error.message })
            };
        }
    }
});

Here is my package.json
{
  "name": "chat",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "main": "src/functions/*.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "func start",
    "test": "echo \"No tests yet...\""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@azure/core-auth": "^1.9.0",
    "@azure/functions": "^4.5.0",
    "@azure/openai": "^1.0.0-beta.7",
    "@azure/web-pubsub": "^1.1.3",
    "axios": "^1.7.7",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "azure-functions-core-tools": "^4.x"
  }
}


Please share your function code and package.json file @CYC

Do you intent to create a V3 or V4 model?

I want to use v4 model

In that case, you shouldn't have function.json in your folder structure. V3 model comes with function.json file whereas V4 doesn't

I remove the function.json, but I can't on azure in azure interface the function is empty (also like fig2). I thought it's wired. When I using function start on my local I can see the text in terminal "[2024-10-20T12:14:12.810Z] Worker process started and initialized.
Functions:
index: [GET,POST] http://localhost:7071/api/index
message: [POST,OPTIONS] http://localhost:7071/api/message
negotiate: [GET,OPTIONS] http://localhost:7071/api/negotiate"

It looks like you haven't created the V4 model JavaScript functions correctly, as V4 model doesn't contains function.json file but V3 does. Folder structure for V4 model should look like below.
|   .funcignore
|   .gitignore
|   host.json
|   index.html
|   local.settings.json
|   package-lock.json
|   package.json
|
+---.vscode
|       extensions.json
|       launch.json
|       settings.json
|       tasks.json
|
+---node_modules
|
\---src
    \---functions
            index.js
            message.js
            negotiate.js

I have given code in package.json file.
{
  "name": "79116585",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "func start",
    "test": "echo \"No tests yet...\""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@azure/functions": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "main": "src/functions/*.js"
}

I also have followed this documentation to create a chat App using V4 model JavaScript Function App. You should be able to see the http triggers endpoint post successful deployment.


I am able to navigate to the index page using the function URL.

I would suggest you to follow the documentation clearly and create the function from the scratch.
